# Magento 2 : Add custom error message after csv import

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport

i am trying to display custom text message after import csv is done in `On the Admin sidebar, go to System > Data Transfer > Import`.

The messages appears but on reload page.
Any thoughts how can i display messages ?

```
protected function _importData(): bool
    {
        switch ($this->getBehavior()) {
            case Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND:
                $complete['notice'] = array(
                    0 => 'Could not load Order ID "2120621" for row no: 2',
                    1 => 'Unable to create credit memo for order #000000025.',
                    2 => 'Could not load Order ID "212062154" for row no: 4',
                );
                foreach ($complete['notice'] as $value) {
                   $this->messageManager->addNotice(__("Notice"));
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: It seems to be tough :)

Comment: have you got any solution?